# Finding permuatitions of a word in a long `String`

Tags: java

I'm trying to find all of the permutations of a `word`(`"abc"` in this case) in the second String. But I'm getting `StringOutOFBoundException`. What's wrong with the code?

```
public class StringPermutations {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int count = findPermutations("abc", "Helloabcwwwabcwwqqqqqqaawwbcwwwwabcabc");
        System.out.println("The number of the permutations of abc is " + count);
    }

    public static int findPermutations(String word, String longString){
        int count = 0;
        int length = word.length();

        String myString = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < longString.length() - length; i++){
            if(longString.substring(i, longString.length() - length - i).equals(word)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop the second parameter to substring is negative sometimes. You want it to be `longString.substring(i, i + length)`

Comment: In this case the code will miss the last occurrence, returning 3 instead of 4.

Comment: The loop should execute until longString.length() - length + 1.

Answer (score 0):

The paramethers for [String.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method cannot be negative.
You should alter de loop condition.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= longString.length() - length; i++){
    if(longString.substring(i, i + length).equals(word)){
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i = 0; i < longString.length() - length + 1; i++){
        if(longString.substring(i, length + i).equals(word)){
            count++;
        }
  }
```

the loop length should be `longString.length() - length + 1`,

and substring `(i, length + i)`.